# A simple move-left-and-right program with a bit of acceleration (ActionScript 3.0, similar to Java)

Tags: actionscript-3

http://pastebin.com/ap6hVRVb

I've fixed everything I can see, but maybe I've looked at it too much and I've grown used to what is wrong in the code, therefore I will have trouble seeing what is incorrect.

Basically I just need a symbol called player to move left and right when I press either A or D or left or right arrow keys.

I'm Still learning code I know I'm pathetic.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I see 
rightDown=false instead of ==. What problems are you having with it exactly?

Comment: I am trying to make a symbol called player mvd left and right with arrow keys and a and d.

Comment: And is it working at all? does the player move in any direction? Does the player even show up on the screen? Just trying to narrow down your problem

Comment: The player loads on the screen, but doesn't respond do my input. It doesn't show any errors and the output (in Adobe Flash CS6) is empty. I've also tried running it in both Adobe Flash and My web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should really end your statements with a semi-colon, man. It also doesn't hurt to use constant variables to store the key codes, so you don't accidentally mistype one.

In the updateSpeed function you have, you might want to change the 'if()' statements to 'else if()' conditionals? I'm not completely sure if that's the problem, but I don't think it'd hurt to try.

Also, as @VBCPP said, there's a line that says

> if(rightDown=false && leftDown==false){

When it should be

> if (rightDown == false && leftDown == false){
>
> OR
>
> if ( !rightDown && !leftDown ){

Comment: That's a bit of an outdated link, I have changed some things. Guess it would have made sense to update it.